# GCC Warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts' is invalid in C99

Tags: macos, gcc

I am beginning Zed Shaw's [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/).  I have downloaded XCode and the Command Line Tools.  But when I compile the very first program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     puts("Hello world."); 
     return 0;
 }
```

I get this warning:

> ex1.c:2:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts' is invalid
>   in C99
>         [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

The program does compile and execute correctly.

I'm using OSX 10.8.3. Entering `'gcc -v'` gives:

> Using built-in specs. Target: i686-apple-darwin11 Configured with:
>   /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure
>   --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local
>   --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Thread model: posix gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Please help.

Comment: The use of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` when the arguments are unused is mildly silly; it should be `int main(void)` or even `int main()` instead.  However, that's a debate for another day, probably.  I note that GCC 5.x uses C11 (`-std=gnu11`) as the default compilation mode.  `clang` (masquerading as `gcc`) uses C99.  Both C99 and C11 require all functions (except `main()`) to be declared before they are used.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to include stdio.h, i.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

at the start to import the function definition.

Comment: Also in lesson 2 Zed points out that you can get rid of the warning by using your include statement.  So I'm crediting you with the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

This "book" should be renamed to **Learn To Hate C By Following Meaningless Examples That Are Blatantly Wrong.**

The correct code in modern C would be plain and easy

```
#include <stdio.h>        // include the correct header

int main(void) {          // no need to repeat the argument mantra as they're not used
    puts("Hello world."); 
}                         // omit the return in main as it defaults to 0 anyway
```

---

While the original example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts("Hello world."); 
    return 0;
}
```

would have been just plain *bad* in 1989, in **1999** (that is 18 years prior to the writing of this answer, and almost as many years before the "book" was written) the C standard was revised. In the C99 revision, this kind of [*implicit function declaration*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#Forewordp5) was made illegal - and [naturally it remains illegal in the current revision of the standard (C11)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp7). Thus using `puts` **without `#include`ing** the relevant header, i.e. prepending `#include <stdio.h>` (or declaring the `puts` function with `int puts(const char*);`) is a **constraint error**.

A constraint error is an error that *must* cause the compiler output a diagnostics message. Additionally such a program is considered an **invalid** program. However the peculiar thing about the C standard is that it allows a C compiler to also successfully compile an invalid program, though a compiler may as well reject it. Therefore, such an example is hardly a good starting point in a book that is supposed to teach C to beginners.

Comment: Is that link the official standard website/repository thingy?

Comment: @Ungeheuer no, unfortunately the [official standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) costs money. This is the HTML version of the C11 final *draft* known by its working name **n1570**.

Comment: Thanks man. Last question. Does the linked website have previous standards? I don't see a way to navigate out of there.

Comment: Where does the Standard specify that any program that violates a constraint is an "invalid program"?  An implementation is allowed to accept such a program or not, at its leisure, provided that it issues a diagnostic, and if there exists any conforming C implementation that accepts some particular blob of text, that blob of text is a conforming C program.